# How to use re to search for items in one list inside another list in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am reading a list of strings, each of which relate to a file name. However, each string is minus the extension. I have come up with the following code:

```
import re
item_list = ['item1', 'item2']
search_list = ['item1.exe', 'item2.pdf']
matches = []
for item in item_list:
    # Match item in search_list using re - I assume this is the best way to do this
    regex = re.compile("^"+item+"\.")
    for file in search_list:
        if regex.match(file):
            matches.append((item, file))
```

As for duplicate matches, I'm not intensely worried about two files being named 'foo.bar' and 'foo.foo.bar'. That being said, is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: Useful to know how many items in each of the two lists, and how often the code will be called.

Comment: @Will, I would say there would thousands of files in the list. The list should be slightly (5% or so) larger than the actual number of files in the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine all the items into one regexp like this which will be more efficient

```
import re
item_list = ['item1', 'item2']
regex = re.compile("^("+"|".join(item_list)+")\.")
search_list = ['item1.exe', 'item2.pdf']
matches = []
for file in search_list:
    match = regex.match(file)
    if match:
        matches.append((match.group(1), file))
```

A better solution might be to parse the filenames using os.path functions though to parse out the basenames and look for them in a set.

Comment: If the items can contain regex-special punctuation like `.`, you'll need to `re.escape` each item in `item_list` before joining.

Comment: Thanks Nick, this post deserves a hundred useful votes! Found the timeit module and ran tests based on my original algorithm, Dave Kirby's algorithm, and yours. The results were as follows:
alex_k : 15.93
dave_kirby : 6.98
nick_craig_wood : 0.24

Answer (score 2):

Use splitext to get the filename without the extension:

```
import os.path

for item in item_list:
    for filename in search_list:
        if item == os.path.splitext(filename)[0]:
            matches.append((item, file))
```

It's more correct, but it's also easier to understand what your intention is from reading the code. Alternatively, if you want to allow foo to match foo.bar.txt then use filename.startswith(item + '.') instead.

Comment: +1 for splitext. Accurately does what it says; more readable than regex.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a regex for this since you are doing exact string matches (no wildcards, groups etc) - you can use **str.startswith(..)** instead.  This is equivalent to your code:

```
for item in item_list:
    match = item + "."
    for file in search_list:
        if file.startswith(match)
            matches.append((item, file))
```

However Nick Craig-Wood's suggestion of compiling all the matches into a single regex may be more efficient - I suggest you benchmark both if speed is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `re` unless you really need it. For simple string matching, you don't really need it.

Mark Byers's answer duplicates the original behaviour of keeping `matches` in `item_list`-order. If you don't need that, you could do it even more simply/quickly:

```
for file in search_list:
    item= os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    if item in item_list:
        matches.append((item, file))
```

If you don't need to keep the `(item)` matched either (since it's redundant from the filename anyway), you've got a one-liner:

```
matches= [file for file in search_list if os.path.splitext(file)[0] in item_list]
```

Comment: They do need to be matched, but thanks for giving a great example of a one-liner!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it that is likely faster than Alex's original code:

```
item_list = ['item1', 'item2']
search_list = ['item1.exe', 'item2.pdf']
matches = []
for item in item_list:
    for filename in search_list:
        if filename.partition(".")[0] == item:
            matches.append((item,filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `.rsplit(".",1)` for that purpose, regex aren't overkill?

```
>>> item_list = ['item1', 'item2','item3']
>>> search_list = ['item1.exe', 'item2.pdf','item9999.txt']
>>>
>>> [(x.rsplit(".",1)[0],x) for x in search_list if x.rsplit(".",1)[0] in item_list]
[('item1', 'item1.exe'), ('item2', 'item2.pdf')]
```

or with for loop

```
matches=[]
for x in search_list:
    y=x.rsplit(".",1)[0]
    if y in item_list:
        matches.append((y,x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for file in search_list:
...  tomatch=file.split(".")[0]
...  if tomatch in item_list:
...     found=item_list.index(tomatch)
...     matches.append( ( file, item_list[found] ) )
...
>>> print matches
[('item1.exe', 'item1'), ('item2.pdf', 'item2')]
>>>
```

No need for regex.